# How to use eclipse with ssh, so that the remote projects can be edited by local eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, ssh

I often use remote servers to store and run my Java projects. But this prevents me from using eclipse. So I have two questions:

1. Can I use my local eclipse manage the Java projects on the remote servers ? ( I usually use `ssh` to access the servers )
2. If there is a solution for question 1, then is it possible that the Java programs run on the remote server also ? (i.e. only the GUI of eclipse is shown local)

For the second question, I know `ssh -X` can do this (run eclipse on the remote server), but it is too slow. Any ideas?

Comment: Usually, I work on these projects by myself.

Comment: agreed, remoting is best via some versioning tool (CVS, SVN, Git, Hg etc) or local with a push to production, but if forced to run like that I'd try mounting a network share (nfs etc)

Comment: you may Google "SSH Network Drive" for 1.  The basic idea is try to mount the remote data as a network drive so you can have Eclipse work on it as it is local files.  For 2, it is a typical X Windows usage.  I have no idea on what's your remote machine, but you can setup a X Server on your local box, and run remote application and ask it to send the display to your machine.  However, neither of the approach is having trivial effort to setup.  Maybe you can share your reason of doing so, and probably there are better way to solve your problem instead of trying to edit remote files

Comment: not exactly what you want for #2, but http://www.nomachine.com/ is dramatically faster than standard X windows.  i use it all the time.  and it's free

Comment: Sounds like a job for _SVN_... Takes care of remote access and version control at the same time.

Comment: ad "ssh -X" and "nomachine.com and sisters" (all of them dramatically faster than standard X windows resp. "ssh -X"): the buzzword is [NX technology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NX_technology) – we recently decided to prefer [X2Go](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X2Go) over nomachine.com.

Answer (score 5):

[RSE plugin](http://www.eclipse.org/tm/) is what you are looking for.

There is [an article](http://www.venukb.com/2007/06/06/how-to-browse-remote-files-in-eclipse-ide/) to introduce it.